# Import private key

Tags: solo-baking, baking-node, encrypted

I was using my tz1 account to bake with bakechain for a while now.

I decided to run my own node to be able to vote on the proposal.

I was able to sync and run my own node but when I try to import my secret key using the command:

```
./tezos-client import secret key my_account
```

I have this error message:

```
"No matching plugin for key scheme"
```

I'm thinking that the issue come from the fact that the extracted private key from Bakechain is encrypted and this command is requesting a non-encrypted secret key.

- Is there a way to make this command working with an encrypted secret key ?
- Or is there a way to easily unencrypt a private key ?

Just for confirmation:

- A encrypted private key usually start with : edsk
- A unencrypted private key is a Hexadecimal chain of character. (And this command line request an unencrypted private key).

Is it right?

Comment: Is your question really "how can I export a private key from Bakechain to tezos-client"? If someone tells you the correct way to import an encrypted (edesk, not edsk) key, will you ask how to get that from Bakechain?

Comment: My question is to be able to import my private key (extracted from bakechain) using the command : ./tezos-client import secret key my_account

But everytime i get the error message : "No matching plugin for key scheme"

I can be wrong but my assumption is that my extracted private key from bakechain is encrypted and this command request an unencrypted private key.

So my question is : is there a way to import an encrypted key or is there a way to extract an unencrypted key with bakechain or how to decode the Bakechain private key.

Answer (score 10):

If you key starts with `edsk`: do this

```
tezos-client import secret key my_account unencrypted:edsk...
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about bakechain, but I can say your `tezos-client` command is incorrect.

It needs to look like:

`./tezos-client import secret key my_account encrypted:edesk1XXXX`

where `encrypted:edesk1XXXX` is the encrypted version of your key.

Comment: My secret key start with edsk ! I try to use your command line and still have the same error message

Comment: Don't know then, sorry. I just know whenever I've seen the error message you posted it was because I used the command wrong and forgot to use the encrypted:edesk1 key.