# I haven't moved my coin to my wallet

Tags: tezos-client

As an early member, I have about 5,000 Tezos. By the way, I have a private Key but I haven't moved my coin to my wallet. How can I move it? please answer me.

Comment: What kind of wallet do you have? AFAIK, you do not actually have to move the coin, you just have to register your private key with your wallet. Then your wallet can control the account, make transactions, etc.

Comment: To import your private key into the wallet contained in `tezos-client`, see the following answer: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/1061/1773

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use Kukai as a [standalone app](https://github.com/kukai-wallet/kukai) (preferably on an clean computer or bootable usb OS) and then move your coin to a hardware wallet like trezor or ledger nano s or x. After that, you should ideally delegate or bake to participate with the tez community and earn staking rewards.